# BETWEEN com campo tipo DATETIME

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Usando o BETWEEN com campos do banco tipo DATETIME o mesmo não retorna os registro com data igual a datai e dataf.

Usando o DATE_FORMAT para fazer a busca por data ignorando o TIME
Considerando a busca $dtai = '01/06/2016' e $dtaf = '06/05/2016', retorna resultados apenas entre 02/06/2016 e 05/05/2016, não retornado dados do período pesquisado, sendo que no banco de dados existem dados para o período pesquisado.

```
SELECT u.Nome, u.Email, DATE_FORMAT(cp.DataSolicitacao,'%d/%m/%Y') as DataSolicitacao, cp.CodigoPromo, cp.IdTransacao
    FROM cartao_pedidos AS cp
    INNER JOIN usuarios AS u ON u.Id = cp.IdUsuario
    INNER JOIN codigospromo AS cpp ON cpp.Numero = cp.CodigoPromo
    WHERE cpp.IdColaborador = :idc AND cp.DataSolicitacao BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT($dtai,'%Y-%m-%d')  AND DATE_FORMAT($dtaf,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

campo DataSolicitacao é tipo DATATIME, e registros no banco de dados gravados com TIME, ex. 2016-05-06 15:51:35.
Estou usando PDO.
Como fazer para retornar os registros com as datas das busca?

Comment: Seus campos estão sem horário, isso é o primeiro problema. Outra coisa é que se está usando PHP, já deve mandar a data certa no formato do SQL, e não usar o DATE_FORMAT. Só faz sentido o DATE_FORMAT pra economizar banda em certas _queries_ (que não é o caso do seu código). Além disso, me parece que os dados que vc passou na pergunta não coincidem com uma situação real, pois do jeito que você fez, era para retornar do dia 1 ao dia 5, e não do dia 2 ao dia 5. Ponha a parte em PHP também, que talvez dê pra consertarmos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você não postou o código PHP, segue o ajuste inicial da *query* apenas:

```
SELECT     u.Nome, u.Email, cp.DataSolicitacao, cp.CodigoPromo, cp.IdTransacao
FROM       cartao_pedidos AS cp
INNER JOIN usuarios AS u ON u.Id = cp.IdUsuario
INNER JOIN codigospromo AS cpp ON cpp.Numero = cp.CodigoPromo
WHERE      cpp.IdColaborador = :idc
           AND cp.DataSolicitacao BETWEEN
                '$datacerta_inicial 00:00:00' AND '$datacerta_final 23:59:59'
```

Idealmente você vai arrumar a data do lado do PHP, e não usar DATE_FORMAT em absolutamente nenhum lugar da *query*.

Um exemplo de acerto de formato em PHP é esse (tem vários outros, depende do seu código):

```
$datacerta_inicial = substr($datai,6,4).'-'.substr($datai,3,2).'-'.substr($datai,0,2);
```

O único sentido que faria de se formatar algo do lado do SQL, seria em situações onde você vai ter uma economia muito grande de banda, como retornar apenas o mês de uma data completa numericamente, e coisas do tipo, e mesmo assim é necessário ver se compensa o processamento extra no servidor.